# USB audio from Pygame

Tags: python, usb, audio, raspbian-stretch

I am running Raspbian Stretch.

I've connected a USB sound device and selected it through the graphic interface.

This sends the sound out fine from youtube in Chrome but is silent with a Python program using Pygame (whether launched on startup or afterwards).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the python-sounddevice module?  This module has functionality which lets you interrogate your system to see what sound devices are available and select which device to use.

[python-sounddevice documentation](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.9/)